# HibernateSessionFactory class doesn't change data from database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

In our application we have an `HibernateSessionFactory` class, that is opening and closing connections. Everything is okay, but when we are updating data in the database, it doesn't change in our application.  Unfortunately, we see old data from the database. How can I fix this?

```
public class HibernateSessionFactory {

    private static final ThreadLocal threadLocal = new ThreadLocal();
    private static org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(
                                        HibernateSessionFactory.class);

    static {
        try {
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                        .buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error Creating SessionFactory", e);
        }
    }

    private HibernateSessionFactory() {}

    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
        if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
            if (sessionFactory == null) {
                rebuildSessionFactory();
            }
            session = (sessionFactory != null) ?
                        sessionFactory.openSession() : null;

            threadLocal.set(session);
        }
        return session;
    }

    public static void rebuildSessionFactory() {

        try {
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                        .buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error Creating SessionFactory", e);
        }
    }

    public static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
        Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
        threadLocal.set(null);
        if (session != null) {
            session.flush();
            session.close();

        }
    }

    public static org.hibernate.SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }

}
```

.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Tauthor> getAuthors() throws HibernateException {
    log.debug("getting all authors");
    Query queryObject = null;
    List<Tauthor> authors = null;
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
    try {
        String queryString = "from Tauthor";
        queryObject = session.createQuery(queryString);
        authors = queryObject.list();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        log.error("get all authors failed", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        HibernateSessionFactory.closeSession();
    }
    return authors;
}
```

Comment: If you've update objects.. you had set properties for those objects!

Comment: You have to do session.flush() after you go past the update statement.

Comment: Can you please also code where you are using hibernate session ?

Comment: @SachinThapa I add that part

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your code where you write data to the database. Without that, I can think of only a few reasons as to why your data output is old instead of new data:

1. Your transactions are not being committed.
2. Hibernate hasn't written to the database at the time of data queried by you.
3. Hibernate's cache hasn't been updated, which results in query returning old data.

You should verify that data has been written to the Database with a db developer tool and try disabling all hibernate caching to see if the result changes.